# How to setup a load-test with JMeter for performing SP initiated SSO's with SAML

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, saml, openam

I want to setup a load-test with JMeter for performing SP initiated SSO's using SAMLv2 with a variety of users. This includes posting the required `AuthNRequest` message to the login URL of the Identity Provider (IDP) but also the credentials (username, password) of the current user.

The `AuthNRequest` must be signed and encrypted so I want to leave that to the service provider (SP) and grab that somehow so I can reuse that (but I don't know if I need to do that in the first place - maybe a follow redirect is sufficient enough).

I find it hard to get my head around which steps to take for getting this done. I don't need exact guidance on where to click in JMeter but more a general overview of the involved HTTP request samplers (including order), pre and post processors and assertions.

We have service providers that support both the [SAML HTTP-POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0#HTTP_POST_Binding) and [SAML HTTP-Redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0#HTTP_Redirect_Binding) binding to transport the `AuthNRequest` to the IDP.

Any help would be great! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've created a blog post with all the necessary steps and can be found here

http://www.martijnburgers.net/post/2013/11/12/Setting-up-a-load-test-with-JMeter-for-performing-SP-initiated-SSOs-with-SAML-20.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why not just record it using new jmeter 2.10 and see what happens.

New 2.10 version better detects redirects and is easier for https, but read carefully:

- http://s.apache.org/GNl

Then variabilize what needs to be.

You should only need:

- Http Sampler
- Cookie Manager
- Maybe post/pre processor but not sure

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I already figured it out my self, doing it all manually. I will post my answer when I've got more time on my hands.